# Connection timed out nginx ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, csv, ubuntu, nginx

I have a csv file of 4200 rows. I have to read this file and work with two api to get the relevant data. My Problem is here every time i am getting connection timed out. I am using php mysql with nginx. I have google for solution and i changed the time out variables in php.ini and www.conf and sites-available/default. Still i am getting the same error even i read a csv file with 50 rows.

```
My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit. Is there any other solution a part from the above?
```

Comment: try this command in your code ini_set('max_execution_time', '2400');

Comment: i have given already in my code like below :
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

Comment: please increase execution time 0 to 2400 and try

Comment: check ini settings, max memory allocated to script, script timeout

Comment: @Pruthviraj:'2400' do we need to compulsory to give this in quotes or without quotes also it works?

Comment: @Mohammad : i found only memory_limit = 128M in php.ini, i didnt find script timed out